# argc and argv aren't running

Tags: c, cmd, argv, argc

Here is what the geany says.
Help appreciated.

rec_pattern_printing.c:5: error: syntax error before '*' token

rec_pattern_printing.c: In function `main':

rec_pattern_printing.c:8: error: `argc' undeclared (first use in this function)

rec_pattern_printing.c:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

rec_pattern_printing.c:8: error: for each function it appears in.)

rec_pattern_printing.c:13: warning: implicit declaration of function `atoi'

rec_pattern_printing.c:13: error: `argv' undeclared (first use in this function)

Compilation failed.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   int main(int argc, *char argv[] )
   { int N;

   if(argc<2)
   printf("Not enough arguments to continue");
   getche();
   return 4;

   N = atoi(argv[1]);
   printf("%d",N);

   }
```

Comment: You need `char *argv[]`. The star comes after type.

Comment: char = type * tells it is a pointer to a char argv is the variable [] is the same as char** argv

Comment: YOu should format your code correctly so it is readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
```